# Non clickable LinearLayout inside Scrollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

How do i make Non Clickable LinearLayout inside ScrollView in android ?
LinearLayout should not respond for any onClicks.How do I make it non-clickable?
Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

XML File looks like this...

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_questions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
       >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
             >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_ques1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_ques2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb1_rg_ques2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mail"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb2_rg_ques2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Cold Calling"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_ques3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_ques4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb1_rg_ques4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1 - 5"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb2_rg_ques4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5 - 10"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb3_rg_ques4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10 - 15"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb4_rg_ques4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="15+"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_ques5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb1_rg_ques5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Daily"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb2_rg_ques5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Weekly"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb3_rg_ques5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Monthly"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb4_rg_ques5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Yearly"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_ques6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb1_rg_ques6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1 - 3"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb2_rg_ques6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4 - 6"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb3_rg_ques6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7 - 9"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb4_rg_ques6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10+"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_ques7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_ques8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_ques9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_ques10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_ques11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_ques12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb1_rg_ques12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Yes"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rb2_rg_ques12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_ques13"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_ques14"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="XXX"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textfontsize" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chk1_ques14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="APAC"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chk2_ques14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Middle East"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chk3_ques14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="South East Asia"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chk4_ques14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Europe"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chk5_ques14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="America"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: .. Share your xml layout code/relevant code.

Comment: Share some code and specify what you need to do with that. it's bit easier.

Comment: Added the XML file.Please Check it.

Comment: Inside the LinearLayout you have multiple RadioButtons and CheckBoxes which are designed to be clicked what are you trying to make non-clickable? If it's the editText boxes try setting their inputType to NULL

Comment: That is just for View not Clickable.By seeing XML page the audio will be recorded. @Hank

Comment: Ok, then I'm pretty sure you have to add android:clickable="false"  to each radioButton and/or checkbox -

Comment: ok i will try... Thanks @Hank

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout attribute `android:clickable="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime set..

```
    linearLayout .setClickable(false);
linearLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

If you want by xml..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout "
        android:clickable="false"/>
```

Comment: Added XML file.Please check it @Kush

Comment: add android:clickable="false" every buttun , radio etc.. @Naveen

Answer (score 0):

set

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout "
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Its Not Working @Nandakishore